# Creation of Table using DBT

Tags: dbt

Can we create a new table in DBT?
Can we copy the table structure which is present in the dev environment in the database to another environment using DBT?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you are trying to achieve? You seem to be asking about basic and well-documented features of dbt: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/introduction

Comment: @tconbeer I have a similar issue where I need to use one user to create a table and another user to fill it due to a different set of permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. However, Dbt needs a "reason" to create tables, for example, to materialize the data produced by one of its models. DBT cannot create table just for the creation's sake.

Well, strictly speaking, you can do this by putting `CREATE TABLE...` in a [pre-hook or post-hook](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook) section, but I suppose this is not what you want since dbt makes no difference here at all.

You can define your existed table in [sources](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources) where you can set database, schema and table name different from the *target* storage space where dbt writes data. And then, define a model something like:

```sql
{{ materialized="table" }}
select * 
from {{ source('your_source', 'existed_table_name') }}
limit 1 /* add "limit 1" if you only want the structure  */
```

Put necessary connection credentials in the `profiles.yml`, and build the model. Dbt will copy one row from source table into model table, before that model table creation is done for free.

Comment: This will still add one row to the table, which might not be possible depending on the user permissions.